# Looking for simple "WebHelper" C# class

Tags: c#, http

I'm looking for a WebHelper class for C#, one that wraps and stuff all the common requests, such as like POSTing and GETting http requests etc.

Comment: Can you give us more detail on your requirements and needs? Maybe a bit on why built in .Net functionality like Mehrdad points out below doesn't work?

Comment: It works but I want a wrapper around it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't `System.Net.WebClient` and `System.Net.WebRequest` already doing this for you pretty elegantly?

Comment: Yea, I want like a wrapper for all that though.  I wanna do like string html = WebHelper.Post(string url, Dictionary<string, string> postdata) etc.etc. I mean I could write my own WebHelper class to do this but I'm sure better ones are out there.

Comment: I agree. These are wrappers around the HttpWebRequest/Response, which is what you'd be doing if you rolled your own "WebHelper."

Comment: `new WebClient().UploadString` pretty much does something like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Data Extracting SDK](http://extracting.codeplex.com/) which has features you need.